# Service enabling itself when it shouldn't

Tags: android

I've added a widget for my application, basically clicking on the widget enables a service.
But sometimes i experience random enabling of the service even if i didn't press the widget

I followed the android developer guide to make the widget and the code looks like this

```
public class ToggleWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static RemoteViews remoteViews;
    boolean status = false;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.toggle_widget);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), WakeService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                    context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bulb_widget, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

            context.startService(intent);

            Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Widget Worked");


         // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }




}
```

This code should run the service intent when i click the ImageButton.
Clicking on it works as it should, but i get those random enablings (the service displays a notification when it's enabled, so i know it's running)
Can you spot something wrong in the code?

Comment: If you take out `context.startService(intent);`, does clicking the widget still start the service?

Comment: Yeah it works, now i get it :) post it as answer so i'll vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out

```
context.startService(intent);
```

Since the `PendingIntent` already starts the Service when the widget is clicked, having an explicit `context.startService()` in `onUpdate()` will make the Service start regardless of whether or not the widget is clicked.